# What causes some industries to go away?

Tags: openttd

Sometimes I've had industries go away - notably oil rigs but sometimes forests or coal mines. I thought it had something to do with proximity to a city but I have some urban forests (ha!) that are still holding up pretty well in 2240. I also thought it might have to do with the transportation percentage, but I always had a decent percentage (>~50%) on the oil rigs and that seemed to make no difference.

Comment: I'm not sure at all about this, so I'm going to put it up as a comment: Oil rigs don't live past a certain time since oil runs out in the end. Renewable resources (like wood) don't at all. If an industry is not properly exploited they tend to go ayway, oil rigs may have a faster decreasing tolerance for this.

Comment: It's just interesting because I've had some rigs for over 200 years. I've been waiting for them to go away all this time and they haven't! I thought they ran out but I guess there's an awful lot of oil to exploit in my seas.

Comment: @lemontwist There's a trick with oil rigs - if you keep the passenger trade ticking over, the oil will never run out...

Comment: @foocode, OK that is definitely the difference between when my oil rigs went away and when they didn't that I never noticed. I keep up the passenger business now and the rigs just stay put. Good to know! I never made that connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Demand</strike> Utilisation also plays a role. If an industry is unused & unsupplied, it will disappear. @Assile's comment is also true in that some industries have a more limited life-time than others - however even renewable industries will close if they're unused (i.e. forests and farms).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but if you don't mess with an industry it will go away. If you don't carry over 50% of an industries cargo, it will close, oil rigs and wells will randomly run out (oil running out maybe?) even if you are carrying 50%+ of their cargo, and oil wells (the oil pumps that are on land) can only appear in certain spots, and due to a glitch from the original TTT-TTD that is still in OpenTTD, even if you work with them, the game still considers them unused, so they will still disapear in a few years. In a recession, however, industries produce half as much, and are twice as likely to shut down.